# how to calculate coordinate point x,y(of inner circle) between two point on a circle circumference?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have two points on circle (x1,y1,x2,y2). I want to find the middle of the points ,but with smaller radius of the circle. like shown in the pic, point X0 and Y0 needed to be calculated. and this process might be repetitive sometimes going further to inner circle.
[image]

i used this sample from stackoverflow thread to calculate points X1,Y1 and X2,Y2.

```
drawPoint(r, currentPoint, totalPoints) {  
    var startPt = {'x':-1,'y':-1,'a':0}
    var theta = ((Math.PI*2) / totalPoints);
    var angle = (theta * currentPoint);
    startPt.a = angle
    startPt.x = (r * Math.cos(angle));
    startPt.y = (r * Math.sin(angle));

    return startPt;
}
```

Now i needed to find imaginary circle points X0,Y0. I calculated the angle on the circle by using the angles from X1 and X2 points and by applying the known radius of smaller circle, i tried to get the inner circle(imaginary) points X0,Y0.

```
getNewEnd(endPt,angle,newSmallRadius){
    endPt.x = (newSmallRadius * Math.cos(angle));
    endPt.y = (newSmallRadius * Math.sin(angle));
}
```

**UPDATE** Found the issue. the issue was in giving the radius, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

In this case of inner circle: 
x0 = x1+x2 / 2 
y0 = y1+y2 / 2

Comment: wont that just give me the X0 ,Y0 on the outer circle and not in the inner circle?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the next approach:

```
midX = (x1 + x2) / 2
midY = (y1 + y2) / 2
len = sqrt(midX*midX + midY*midY)
x0 = r * midX / len
y0 = r * midY / len
```

Now `(x0,y0)` lies at bisector of old points at distance `r` from the origin